# Add a symbol after the name+number in listof

Tags: table-of-contents, newfloat

I created another list instead of \listoftables and \listoffigures. I need to add the symbol "--" after the name "Quadro" on the toc list for this created list. I did it for \listoffigures and for \listoftables, but the solution doesn't work for a different list created by \newfloat, because this solution was using \tocloft.

Part of my .cls file to create this new list

```
\RequirePackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}

\newfloat{quadro}{htb!}{loq}[chapter]
\floatname{quadro}{Quadro}
\newcommand{\listofquadros}

\renewcommand*{\listof}[2]{%
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
    \@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{3em}{2.6em}}%
    %\float@listhead{#2}%
    \begin{center}\textbf{\Large {#2}}\end{center}
    \begingroup\setlength{\parskip}{\z@}%
       \@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}%
    \endgroup}%
   \cleardoublepage%
}
```

The main .tex file

```
    {
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{Quadro~\oldnumberline}
%   \renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{\enspace--\enspace}
    \listof{quadro}{Lista de Quadros}

    \centering  \listofquadros \thispagestyle{empty}   \clearpage
}
```

This was the solution for \listoftables

```
 { 
    \begin{center}
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}
    \renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{\enspace--\enspace}
    \listoftables  \thispagestyle{empty}   \clearpage
    \end{center}
    }
```

The gol is to have this symbol "--" in front of the word 'Quadro' in the second image below on the list created by \newfloat. The current result for \listoftables it's like this:
[image: This is the result I want]

And this is happening now:

[image: There is no the symbol "--"]

Comment: Remember that `\numberline` actually takes an argument. It's somewhat hidden in your redefinition via `\oldnumberline`. But perhaps try with `\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{Quadro~\oldnumberline{#1\enspace--}}`.

Comment: It worked @Werner!! Thanks a lot. I had already given up and accepted to do it manually haha.

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `\numberline` actually takes an argument. It's hidden in your redefinition via `\oldnumberline`, since `\oldnumberline` is called as the last token within the updated `\numberline`. You can explicitly capture the argument so you can place something after it. For example,

```
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{Quadro~\oldnumberline{#1\enspace--}}
```